# Remove a single named volume with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is this possible from `docker-compose` - or do I have identify the volumes location and delete them?

I can only find functionality to delete ALL the volumes associated with the docker-compose.yaml config file.

Comment: `docker volume rm my-volume`? Which command are you currently using?

Comment: `docker-compose stop -v` which removes all the associated volumes.

Comment: Wow, I can't even find that in the official docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compose can only remove all volumes defined in a yml file, or none

```bash
$ docker-compose down -v
```

If you don't want to investigate which volumes are used for the current compose file and remove them with `docker volume rm X`, then create a cutdown compose file that only lists the volumes you want to remove

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "2.1"
volumes:
  one:
  two:
  three:
```

`docker-compose-cleanup.yml`

```yaml
version: "2.1"
volumes:
  two:
```

Then you can act on different sets depending on the compose file

```bash
$ docker-compose up
```

```
Creating volume "composevolumes_three" with default driver
Creating volume "composevolumes_two" with default driver
Creating volume "composevolumes_one" with default driver
Attaching to
```

```bash
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-cleanup.yml down -v
```

```
Removing volume composevolumes_two
```